# Managed apache 2.2 mod_rewrite not working with .htaccess

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

**Problem**: Im getting 503 error when trying to get a managed apache server to proxy through to a simple node API

**Details**: Im working on a managed Red Hat Linux server with Apache/2.2.15 serving static files for each user from their /home/*/public_html. In my case, this makes my static files available from `https://the-managed-domain.com/~avivaldus/`. Im trying to get a simple REST API up and running from within my designated space so that its routes are publicly accessible, i.e. routes like:

```
https://the-managed-domain.com/~avivaldus/getsth
```

... are mapped to e.g. a node cexpress get request. To get this working, I've tried running a simple node express server on `localhost:3001` from within `public_html` (though I dont think that location matters), and with a `.htaccess` file placed within the dir `~/public_html/getsth` with the contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:3001/$1 [P]
```

Unfortunately, the public user receives a 503 error "Service Temporarily Unavailable. The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later. Apache/2.2.15 (Scientific Linux) Server at www.the-managed-domain.com Port 443"

**Any ideas what the problem is here? Without root permissions I can't even inspect the apache error logs to get a better sense as to why this is failing. I managed to get this working though on a separate EC2 instance. **

Comment: Similar problem experienced here: https://serverfault.com/q/941204/497949